# upgrading python 2.7 to 3.x for Django

Tags: python, django, version

I'd like to upgrade python version to 3.x for my Django project.

It's currently using python-2.7.

I failed to find a step by step guide on this.

Not sure how hard this is going to be...

Comment: You can find some tips here: [Porting/Support tips](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/python3/)

Comment: You can create a new virtualenv with python 3 and then activate it and use it

Answer (score 2):

This is a community wiki post. Feel free to add to this post in case you find something missing.

### Change Python path

You will need to change Python path from *Python27* to *Python34* (or whatever version of Python you're using).

This is necessary because whenever you'll do `django-admin.py startproject mysite`, command prompt will access only that script which is in your `Path`.

For editing `Path` variable: [How to add Python path in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)

### Automatic Python2 to Python3 code translation using `lib2to3`

`lib2to3` will take care of most of the things which need to be rewritten for Python3.

```
class MyModel(...):
    ...
    def __unicode__(self):
         ...
```

above code will be changed to:

```
class MyModel(...):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        ...
```

[Docs for `lib2to3`](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/2to3.html)

**NOTE:** `lib2to3` will only change keywords etc. You'll need to change which modules you're using manually. For example, you'll have to change `import StringIO` to `import io` manually.

### Manual code translation

In case you want to do everything manually, here's a checklist for you:

1. Replace `__unicode__` with `__str__`
2. Change `print` statement to `print()` function

   I don't think anybody uses `print` in Django. But if you are, do change it.
3. Replace `StringIO` and `cStringIO` with `io`

   `StringIO.StringIO` becomes `io.StringIO`. There is no `cStringIO` in Python3.